# Need help identifying school anime with short, blonde female character

Tags: seitokai-yakuindomo

Sorry for vague question. All I remember is:

1. School anime
2. Pretty sure not harem
3. Funny
4. Centers on small group of students, both male and female, maybe a club.
5. Normal, yellow and white, sweater and tee style uniforms.
6. Short, blonde female character, flat chested. Not a boobilicious anime.
7. Not a children's anime, crude humor involved.

Please let me know any suggestions at all! :3

Comment: When did you saw it ? When was it probably made ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess [**Seitokai Yakuindomo**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8675/Seitokai_Yakuindomo).

1. School anime

   - Yes.
2. Not harem

   - Well, harems are in the eye of the beholder, but pretty much yes.
3. Funny

   - Allegedly.
4. Centers on small group of students, both male and female

   - One guy and three girls in the student council
5. Normal yellow/white uniforms

   - [image: SYD main cast]
     　(their shirts are white beneath the blazers)
6. Short, blonde, flat-chested female

   - See above (Hagimura Suzu)
7. Crude humor

   - [Oh good lord yes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDD40_1LRUg).

Comment: `Not harem` There are at least 2-3 girls hinted to like the main character, so I wouldn't be so sure.